# nginx docker instance multiple application

Tags: php, nginx, docker, dockerfile

So, I am Dockerizing my architecture which consists of multiple php applications ran on apache.

If I'm right I need: **1 nginx container**, **1 php container** and multiple **data-containers** to `volume-from` in the nginx container.

How would I be able to have multiple data container linked to my nginx container?
So for example I got `app1.domain.com` volumed to `/data/app1` and `app2.domain.com` volumed to `/data/app2` etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can create one volume container for each app:

- app1: `docker create -v /data/app1 --name app1 ....`
- app2: `docker create -v /data/app2 --name app2 ....`

Then link them to your `nginx` container with:

```
docker run --volumes-from app1 --volumes-from app2 --name nginx ... nginx ...
```

More information about volumes you can find [in the official volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Comment: And link the php and nginx to each other?

Comment: I would install `nginx` and `php-fpm` on the same image.

Comment: @guidsen you should use docker-compose for that.

Comment: @h3nrik so I would have a nginx-php container for each components that has a volume from a data container? Because I got issues running multiple application on the same nginx-php container.

Comment: No. The idea is to have only one single nginx/php container with the server installation and many data containers. What kind of issues do you have? Are they worth a separate question?

Comment: The question is how I would have different applications running on one nginx-php container. I can't get my vhosts working properly.

Comment: Could you give an example of your nginx configuration?